# Azure Resource Manager Template need help removing IP restrictions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a static website hosted on Azure storage account and I had added IP Restrictions to only allow certain users to access this website.  Now that we are going live, I want to allow all IP addresses to access the site.  Is there a way using Azure Resource Manager where I can allow all IPs to access this static website?

I literally spent all afternoon searching Microsoft docs to find this information and I have not found any reference.

CM

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, you could accept it as answer.

Comment: I ended up using a power shell script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not support it now. ARM templates are meant for controlling the `Control Plane` whereas [`Static Websites Settings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/) feature is exposed as part of Data Plane which is accessed by [Storage Service REST AP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/)I.

If you still want to achieve this feature, you could go to [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) forum to give you idea.